# Refactoring try blocks with async/await

Tags: python, python-3.x, async-await

I have two functions which I would like to simplify. They have largely the same logic, but one is asynchronous and uses one await in a try block. I'd like to have the logic in one place, but could not figure out a clean way of doing that. Any suggestions?

```
from requests import get, HTTPError

# Dummy functions for external functionality
def sync_send(url):
    return get(url)

async def async_send(url):
    return get(url)


def next(url):
    if url is None:
        return

    try:
        response = sync_send(url)
        return response.json()
    except HTTPError as e:
        if e.response.status_code == 404:
            return
        else:
            raise

async def async_next(url):
    if url is None:
        return

    try:
        response = await async_send(url)
        return response.json()
    except HTTPError as e:
        if e.response.status_code == 404:
            return
        else:
            raise
```

So the point of this all is to provide a way of requesting for resources in an API two ways, sync and async. Despite the simple (synchronous) dummy functions, in `async_next` we use asynchronous IO to retrieve things. Other than that, the situation is exactly as it is here.

---

I have accepted that the `if url is None` cannot be refactored, and I currently think my only option is to make a more complex exception hierarchy, raising a dedicated 404 error to catch it without logic. Any other ideas?

Comment: What happened with passing the `cond` variable?

Comment: @Mast When asking this question I thought without further context it would be weird to assume that someone would pass in an empty URL. But when I thought about it again, it is better to have it as it is in the code.

Answer (score 1):

Let's have async implementation:

```
async def async_next(url):
    if url is None:
        return

    try:
        response = await async_send(url)
        return response.json()
    except HTTPError as e:
        if e.response.status_code == 404:
            return
        else:
            raise
```

Then you can provide following sync bridge:

```
def next(url):
    return asyncio.run(async_next(url))
```

Or the following if the event loop is available and running:

```
def next(url):
    return loop.run_until_complete(async_next(url))
```

Note: [check asyncio high level commands](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-api-index.html) for more details

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, though I'm not a fan of running the loop every time a synchronous call should be made.